# Walking and running both with the traffic and against it in city designated bike lanes with a solid white line making out the bike lane

Tags: bike-lane

Tucson AZ has a ton of marked out bike lanes on the city roads. I am routinely forced out into the traffic to avoid runners and walking going both directions with the traffic and the against.
The Question why would the walkers and runners think it is ok to not at least move over even a little for the bike riders.

Comment: I see this kind of behaviour all the time.  It's like as soon as cars are restricted from a space it immediately becomes extra pedestrian space regardless of its actual purpose.  People are just entitled.

Comment: Well, the roads belong to the public. To operate an inherently dangerous motor on them you need a license. That's why we get to use them, so we can't really reject other uses. Do they not move when you ring your bell?-)

Comment: Is this a question about bikes?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest explanation is poor road etiquette mixed with lack of knowledge.

They are aware that if they would do the same on the road they would become corpses within a short time, they probably don't expect anything bad to happen on a bike path because "there are no cyclists" or "the cyclist will move around". Sometimes it is caused by the lack of an equally convenient pedestrian sidewalk, sometime is plain old not caring.

Out of personal experience, doing what you describe in Amsterdam or other Dutch cities provides a free crash course in Dutch cussing, while in other countries I see a behavior similar to what you describe.

Comment: Pedestrians may also think they won’t be badly hurt if they get hit by a cyclist. Which is _usually_ true, especially compared to being hit by a car, but not always, and many people don’t realize just how much of an issue even ‘minor’ injuries can be.

Answer (score 0):

> The Question why would the walkers and runners think it is ok to not at least move over even a little for the bike riders.

Lack of basic manners being taught at home and in school, and no repercussions. It doesn't really happen here.